# Setting multiple Google Map pins in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

Have a React App with a map on it. On the app the user clicks a button and that sends a new group of locations to my Map component. The code below drops the pins just fine but when I click the next button sending a new set of location info I don't know how to remove the old pins. This just adds the new ones and leaves the old ones. Any time I try to use some kind of setState method inside my updatePins, outside the map function, function I get this error.

```
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly
calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate.
React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

Here is the Component code;

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Map extends Component {
  state = {};

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onScriptLoad = this.onScriptLoad.bind(this);
  }

  onScriptLoad() {
    var map = new window.google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById(this.props.id),
      this.props.options
    );

    this.setState({ map });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (!window.google) {
      var s = document.createElement("script");
      s.type = "text/javascript";
      s.src = `https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY`;
      var x = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
      x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
      // Below is important.
      //We cannot access google.maps until it's finished loading
      s.addEventListener("load", e => {
        this.onScriptLoad();
      });
    } else {
      this.onScriptLoad();
    }
  }

  updatePins = locations => {

    locations.map(location => {

      var marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
        position: { lat: location.latitude, lng: location.longitude },
        map: this.state.map,
        title: location.title
      });

    });

  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{ width: "75%", height: "90%", margin: "10px auto" }}
        id={this.props.id}
      >
        {this.updatePins(this.props.locations)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Map;
```

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your code but unable to, can you please post a codesandbox or stackblitz so that we can reproduce this issue from our side please?